# How to change index dtype of pandas DataFrame to int32?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

A default dtype of DataFrame index is `int64` and I would like to change it to `int32`.

I tried changing it with [`pd.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and NumPy array of `int32`, also tried making new index with `dtype=np.int32`. It didn't work, always returning index of `int64`.

Can someone show a working code to produce Pandas index with `int32` size?

I use conda Pandas v0.20.1.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be possible... I could be wrong, but i couldn't find a way yet... `pd.Index(np.arange(10, dtype=np.32), dtype=np.int32)` - returns `Int64Index([...], dtype='int64')`

Comment: Well, I did the same and couldn't figure out. Now trying to look through the source code here https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/c8dafb5a7ae9fe42b9d15c47082a6fb139e78b5d/pandas/core/indexes but don't see where this change happens.

Comment: [I could find support only for `np.int64`, `np.uint64` and `np.float64` for "numeric" indices](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/c8dafb5a7ae9fe42b9d15c47082a6fb139e78b5d/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py)

Comment: Is the goal of using `int32` to save memory? Are the values in the index consecutive, or regularly spaced? If so, then a `RangeIndex` might suffice. It is a memory-saving special case of `Int64Index`. It saves memory by merely storing the start, stop and step values without enumerating all the values in the range.

Comment: @unutbu yep, that's the correct answer. That's exactly what I learned from the core contributor https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is something worth doing in practice, but the following should work:

```
class Int32Index(pd.Int64Index):
    _default_dtype = np.int32

    @property
    def asi8(self):
        return self.values

i = Int32Index(np.array([...], dtype='int32'))
```

(from [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16404#issuecomment-303066852))

Comment: In pandas 0.22.0 this doesn't work as expected. i.sort_values will cut the index in (exactly) half. No idea why.

`i = np.arange(0, 600002, dtype=np.int32);
arr = Int32Index(i, name="i");
arr2 = arr.sort_values();
print arr.shape, arr2.shape;
assert arr.shape == arr2.shape`

Answer (score 1):

All of the code paths I could find, coerce the dtype:

Check in `pandas.Index.__new__()`

```
if issubclass(data.dtype.type, np.integer):
    from .numeric import Int64Index
    return Int64Index(data, copy=copy, dtype=dtype, name=name)
```

This allows passing a dtype, but in `NumericIndex().__new__()` we have:

```
if copy or not is_dtype_equal(data.dtype, cls._default_dtype):
    subarr = np.array(data, dtype=cls._default_dtype, copy=copy)
```

Which changes the dtype.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone show a working code to produce pandas index with int32
>   size?

[@PietroBattiston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44111067/9209546) may work. But it's worth explaining why you should ordinarily *not* want to replace the default `RangeIndex` with an `Int64` / `Int32` index.

Storing the logic behind a range of values takes less memory than storing each integer in a range. This should be clear when you compare, for instance, Python's built-in `range` with NumPy `np.arange`. As described in the [`pd.RangeIndex` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.RangeIndex.html):

> `RangeIndex` is a memory-saving special case of `Int64Index` limited
>   to representing monotonic ranges. Using `RangeIndex` may in some
>   instances improve computing speed.